# Checkout loader keeps loading in Magento 2.3.7

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I try to checkout the purchase it keeps loading all the time. My question is about purchase page loading issue. I've checked the console & there is error like this -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "scope:
function(){return '' }"
    Message: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return
getTemplate() }"
    Message: getTemplate is not defined
    at template (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator
(knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:3:61)
    at init (knockout.js:5454)
    at knockout.js:3358
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1470)
    at knockout.js:3357
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:159)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3343)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3223)
    at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3205)
    at Object.ko.applyBindingsToDescendants (knockout.js:3421)
```

**PHP version:** 7.4

**Magento version:** 2.3.7

**Theme version:** Pearl Theme for Magento 2 Open Source v1.10.15 (Aug 31, 2021)

**Expected results:** After click on checkout button, checkout page should be open.

**Received result:** Checkout loader keeps loading, after a click on proceed to the checkout page.

Comment: If you use any third party extension for any checkout related functionality then try to disable that and then check.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but already followed this step but not work for me.

Comment: Have you check with the default theme change?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the issues into this way.

1. Try to compile one's using this command and then check.

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

2. Try to disable all third party extension and then check if this working or not.
3. Lastly you can cross check the things by setting default `Luma` Theme on frontend.

Comment: Point 1: Already execute but no luck
Point 2: Disable all but no luck
Point 3: For luma and blank theme its working perfect, but for pearl theme its not.

Comment: so that mean issues from your theme that is confirm.

Comment: Yes, Issue with Pearl Theme for Magento 2 Open Source v1.10.15 (Aug 31, 2021)